# Odoo Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined settings view

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I've created 2 new field on *res.config.settings*. At the first, it worked fine, but then I had to update module because of some changes and now I'm not able to see **General configuration** view.
I'm receiving this:

[image: Error]

At first, my code looked like this:

```
class TicketSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    template_id = fields.Many2one('mail.template', string='Mail template')
    days = fields.Integer('Days')

    def set_values(self):
        super(TicketSettings, self).set_values()
        settings = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
        settings.set_param('base.template_id', self.template_id.id)
        settings.set_param('base.days', self.days)

    @api.model
    def get_values(self):
        res = super(TicketSettings, self).get_values()
        settings = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
        template_id = settings.get_param('base.template_id')
        days = settings.get_param('base.days')
        res.update(
            template_id = literal_eval(template_id) if template_id else None,
            hours = literal_eval(days) if days else None)
        return res
```

Then, I made changes, only the name of one field (*days* to *hours*):

```
class TicketSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    template_id = fields.Many2one('mail.template', string='Mail template')
    hours = fields.Integer('hours')

    def set_values(self):
        super(TicketSettings, self).set_values()
        settings = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
        settings.set_param('base.template_id', self.template_id.id)
        settings.set_param('base.hours', self.hours)

    @api.model
    def get_values(self):
        res = super(TicketSettings, self).get_values()
        settings = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
        template_id = settings.get_param('base.template_id')
        hours = settings.get_param('base.hours')
        res.update(
            template_id = literal_eval(template_id) if template_id else None,
            hours = literal_eval(hours) if hours else None)
        return res
```

I've also tried:

- Uninstall and re install
- Comment the view in ***manifest**.py*
- Upgrade base module
- Deleting records generated on **ir.config_parameter**

What's going here?